# how to restrict direct access to a view for registered users, in a custom component, in joomla?

Tags: authentication, joomla1.5, custom-component

I am developing a component, and i am having my own login form and tables.

After authentication of user through my component, userinfo is being stored in Session.
Everything is fine. but user is able to access the views that are supposed to be viewed by logged in users.

I wanted to restrict the access through link. How to do it? Is it possible to so.

Note: I am not using joomla user login. I am using my own component.

Kindly help me to protect the views, and must be displayed after user logged in.

How can i accomplish this task?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Check for advanced settings and set view access to Registered. 9jera.com